# How is the calender on the iPad implemented? How to replicate look of it?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uikit, xamarin.ios

I will have to implement a calendar view/controller that looks pretty much like the one on iPad. Only differences are the list view and I will not have a yearly and daily view. 
Also there is no interactivity in the calendar grid (no moving appointments around).

My idea is currently to have the calendar grid drawn manually in `drawRect:` and use customized `UIViews` for the events and place those on top.

Does anybody have a better idea to realize such a view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a UICalendar project here which also works on iPad. You may have to fiddle with some things to get the images to stretch across the screen bounds, but the event list view works just as you'd expect:

https://github.com/Clancey/UICalendar.git

[image]

Comment: And it is even written in C#! Excellent! Thanks!